# JavaScript - Wait for a promise to finish before next loop iteration

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise

I am trying to make a web application that allows the user to upload a pdf file, take clips of it with a horizontal and vertical selector, then once they have a list of the clips selected, they can rearrange them in whatever order they want, and the application then makes a new pdf file with those clips in that order.

The problem is, the application ends up frequently putting the clips into the new pdf file out of order.

I figure the issue with the code is the promise that happens to read each page and paste the clips is not finished before the application goes to the next iteration in the loop. I have tried putting the for loop inside an async function, and beginning the promise with await, but nothing seems to work.

What can I do to fix this?

The code:

```
var currentWriteHeight = 0; //used to determine how much is on a page in the new pdf before a new one must be created

// open the pdf file to be clipped
const fileName = '../static/upload/' + fileData['fileName'];
pdfjsLib.getDocument(fileName).then((pdfRead) => {

    // create new pdf file
    var hSize = fileData['maxPageWidth'];
    var vSize = fileData['maxPageHeight'];
    const pdfWrite = new jsPDF({unit: 'px',format: [hSize, vSize]});

    // this is the array that states what order the clips are in in the new file
    const positionArray = JSON.parse(fileData['positionArray']);

    for (const x in positionArray) {

        //get data for current clip
        const currentClip = clipData[positionArray[x]];
        const currentPage = currentClip['pageNumber'];

        // put current page in a canvas
        pdfRead.getPage(currentPage).then((page) => {
            const canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
            const ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: true });
            const viewport = page.getViewport(1);
            canvas1.width = viewport.width;
            canvas1.height = viewport.height;

            page.render({
                canvasContext: ctx,
                viewport: viewport
            }).then((rendered) => {

                // crop page down to dimensions specified in clip data
                const minY = currentClip['minY'] * (page.view[3] - page.view[1]) / 600;
                const maxY = currentClip['maxY'] * (page.view[3] - page.view[1]) / 600;
                let minX = 0; 
                let maxX = (page.view[2] - page.view[0]);
                if (currentClip['minX'] != null && currentClip['maxX'] != null) {
                minX = currentClip['minX'] * (page.view[3] - page.view[1]) / 600;
                maxX = currentClip['maxX'] * (page.view[3] - page.view[1]) / 600;
                }
                const clipImgData = ctx.getImageData(minX, minY, (maxX - minX), (maxY - minY));
                canvas1.width = (maxX - minX);
                canvas1.height = (maxY - minY);
                ctx.putImageData(clipImgData, 0, 0);

                // if current image would put total over page height, make new page
                if ((currentWriteHeight + canvas1.height) > vSize) {
                    pdfWrite.addPage({format: [hSize, vSize]});
                    currentWriteHeight = 0;
                }

                // add image to page
                pdfWrite.addImage(canvas1, 'PNG', 0, currentWriteHeight, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
                currentWriteHeight += canvas1.height;

                // if this is the last image, show the new pdf file
                if (x == positionArray.length - 1) {
                    window.open(pdfWrite.output('bloburl'), '_blank');
                }

            });

            canvas1.remove();

        });

    }

});
```

Sample data used:

```
fileData =

fileName: "48 Moonrunner.pdf"
maxPageHeight: 509.28
maxPageWidth: 315.75359999999995
positionArray: "[0, 19, 20, 2, 3, 22, 21, 14, 15, 16, 17, 11, 9, 4, 5, 8, 12, 13, 10, 6, 18, 7, 1]"

clipData = 

0: {pageNumber: 1, minY: 0, maxY: 600, minX: 413, maxX: 773}
1: {pageNumber: 19, minY: 49, maxY: 296, minX: 372, maxX: 721}
2: {pageNumber: 20, minY: 49, maxY: 360, minX: 0, maxX: 372}
3: {pageNumber: 27, minY: 438, maxY: 555, minX: 372, maxX: 721}
4: {pageNumber: 32, minY: 310, maxY: 367, minX: 364, maxX: 715}
5: {pageNumber: 33, minY: 48, maxY: 107, minX: 0, maxX: 364}
6: {pageNumber: 36, minY: 324, maxY: 544, minX: 0, maxX: 364}
7: {pageNumber: 39, minY: 296, maxY: 558, minX: 364, maxX: 721}
8: {pageNumber: 43, minY: 286, maxY: 417, minX: 0, maxX: 364}
9: {pageNumber: 59, minY: 59, maxY: 283, minX: 364, maxX: 715}
10: {pageNumber: 83, minY: 312, maxY: 545, minX: 364, maxX: 715}
11: {pageNumber: 87, minY: 222, maxY: 552, minX: 364, maxX: 721}
12: {pageNumber: 91, minY: 0, maxY: 600, minX: 0, maxX: 364}
13: {pageNumber: 91, minY: 51, maxY: 340, minX: 364, maxX: 715}
14: {pageNumber: 96, minY: 158, maxY: 382, minX: 0, maxX: 364}
15: {pageNumber: 104, minY: 53, maxY: 273, minX: 364, maxX: 715}
16: {pageNumber: 107, minY: 0, maxY: 600, minX: 0, maxX: 364}
17: {pageNumber: 107, minY: 53, maxY: 444, minX: 364, maxX: 721}
18: {pageNumber: 112, minY: 331, maxY: 552, minX: 0, maxX: 364}
19: {pageNumber: 120, minY: 0, maxY: 600, minX: 0, maxX: 364}
20: {pageNumber: 120, minY: 54, maxY: 446, minX: 364, maxX: 721}
21: {pageNumber: 123, minY: 284, maxY: 550, minX: 0, maxX: 364}
22: {pageNumber: 127, minY: 56, maxY: 324, minX: 364, maxX: 715}
```

Comment: Rewrite your code to `async/await`. Then you can simply do `for (...) { ... await yourPromise(); ...}`

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code to use `async`/`await`. This has a few benefits on top of fixing your original issue:

- reduces the amount of indentation
- reduces the complexity
- stops you having to detect the last iteration of your loop - the open window code just goes outside the loop

---

```
var currentWriteHeight = 0; //used to determine how much is on a page in the new pdf before a new one must be created

// open the pdf file to be clipped
const fileName = '../static/upload/' + fileData['fileName'];
const pdfRead = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(fileName);

// create new pdf file
var hSize = fileData['maxPageWidth'];
var vSize = fileData['maxPageHeight'];
const pdfWrite = new jsPDF({unit: 'px',format: [hSize, vSize]});

// this is the array that states what order the clips are in in the new file
const positionArray = JSON.parse(fileData['positionArray']);

for (const x in positionArray) {

    //get data for current clip
    const currentClip = clipData[positionArray[x]];
    const currentPage = currentClip['pageNumber'];

    // put current page in a canvas
    const page = await pdfRead.getPage(currentPage);

    const canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: true });
    const viewport = page.getViewport(1);
    canvas1.width = viewport.width;
    canvas1.height = viewport.height;

    const rendered = await page.render({
        canvasContext: ctx,
        viewport: viewport
    });

    // crop page down to dimensions specified in clip data
    const minY = currentClip['minY'] * (page.view[3] - page.view[1]) / 600;
    const maxY = currentClip['maxY'] * (page.view[3] - page.view[1]) / 600;
    let minX = 0; 
    let maxX = (page.view[2] - page.view[0]);
    if (currentClip['minX'] != null && currentClip['maxX'] != null) {
        minX = currentClip['minX'] * (page.view[3] - page.view[1]) / 600;
        maxX = currentClip['maxX'] * (page.view[3] - page.view[1]) / 600;
    }
    const clipImgData = ctx.getImageData(minX, minY, (maxX - minX), (maxY - minY));
    canvas1.width = (maxX - minX);
    canvas1.height = (maxY - minY);
    ctx.putImageData(clipImgData, 0, 0);

    // if current image would put total over page height, make new page
    if ((currentWriteHeight + canvas1.height) > vSize) {
        pdfWrite.addPage({format: [hSize, vSize]});
        currentWriteHeight = 0;
    }

    // add image to page
    pdfWrite.addImage(canvas1, 'PNG', 0, currentWriteHeight, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
    currentWriteHeight += canvas1.height;  

    canvas1.remove();

}
window.open(pdfWrite.output('bloburl'), '_blank');
```